# webpage not found is shown

Tags: android, webview

I have my android activity  :

```
webView=new WebView(this);   
WebSettings settings=webView.getSettings();  
       settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");  
        setContentView(webView);
```

But it displays me google page is not available. I have added use INTERNET PERMISSION In manifest.

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: Check your internet connection settings to emulator whether proxy and port are entered correct or not.

Comment: no.. everything is fine. If I type in the google url, it opens in the browser. But it doesn't iopen through application.

Comment: set system proxy and port in your oncreate() check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818868/java-net-socketexception-address-family-not-supported-by-protocol-in-android-em/8819835#8819835

Answer (score 2):

Please check your internet connection, open the android browser and check if that page loads there

Answer (score 0):

See if you have used WebViewClient. There are scenarios when you miss it and the web page does not open. [Look into this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) for more details