# error in parsing xml file

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Hi i create one save11111.xml file and place on server. [Here is code of .xml file](http://pastebin.com/AdMJdZWH)
I need to fetch data from that file. but when i am trying to run file it show error in
Log cat. Here is logcat

```
04-14 19:18:58.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22682): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.examguide/com.example.examguide.ReadBooksActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
04-14 19:18:58.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22682): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
04-14 19:18:58.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22682):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:572)
04-14 19:18:58.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22682):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-14 19:18:58.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22682):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-14 19:18:58.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22682):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-14 19:18:58.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22682):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:292)
04-14 19:18:58.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22682):     at com.example.examguide.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:45)
04-14 19:18:58.137: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(22682):     at com.example.examguide.ReadBooksActivity.onCreate(ReadBooksActivity.java:43)
```

I don't understand what's wrong in my code.[Here and](http://pastebin.com/TCTQwERa) [Here](http://pastebin.com/K0mwN5rh)

Please give me some hint or reference.
Any help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the protocol in your URL:

```
        static final String URL = "http://www.cerebrumtechno.com/Save.xml";
```

Comment: flo is correct - someone else had the same issue as described here: http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/04/29/android-odd-error-in-defaulthttpclient/

Comment: @flo,@templer: Thanks guys.....give me one help....now my application run but it doesn't show anything.....show debug message in logcat "address family not supported"..thanks again

Comment: Just google your error message. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854300/java-net-socketexception-address-family-not-supported-by-protocol

Comment: it's problem of my xml file..i solve it but now no error in logcat but emulator not showing anything