# writing to WCF post json from Android client and saving data to sql server 2008

Tags: android, json, wcf

I am facing problem when posting data through WCF service. I have hosted wcf service and working fine with my .net website but it is not working with my android client, I am unable to understand what is happening, Can anyone help me to resolve this problem? Here is my android and wcf code:

WCF Service:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,UriTemplate = "insert")]
         string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo);
    }     

 public class UserDetails
    {
        string username = string.Empty;
        string fname = string.Empty;
        string lname = string.Empty;
        string loc = string.Empty;

        [DataMember]
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return username; }
            set { username = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return fname; }
            set { fname = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lname; }
            set { lname = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Location
        {
            get { return loc; }
            set { loc = value; }
        }

    }

namespace CRUDWCFService
{
    // NOTE: If you change the class name "Service1" here, you must also update the reference to "Service1" in Web.config and in the associated .svc file.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }


         public string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)
        {
            string Message;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.1.99;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=sa;Password=zaeveypws21");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into UserInformation(UserName,FirstName,LastName,Location) values(@UName,@FName,@LName,@Location)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UName", userInfo.UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", userInfo.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", userInfo.LastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", userInfo.Location);

            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                Message = userInfo.UserName + " Details inserted successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                Message = userInfo.UserName + " Details not inserted successfully";
            }
            con.Close();
            return Message;
        }
    }
    }
```

Here is my Android code:

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);

        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {

                    Editable UserName = inputUName.getText();
                    Editable FirstName = inputFName.getText();
                    Editable LastName = inputLName.getText();
                    Editable Location = inputLoc.getText();

                    boolean isValid = true;



                    if (isValid) {

                        // POST request to <service>/insert
                        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.99/wcfinsert/Service1.svc/insert");
                        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                        // Build JSON string
                        JSONStringer userInfo = new JSONStringer().object()
                                .key("userInfo").object().key("UserName")
                                .value(UserName).key("FirstName")
                                .value(FirstName).key("LastName")
                                .value(LastName).key("Location")
                                .value(Location).endObject().endObject();
                        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(userInfo.toString());

                        request.setEntity(entity);

                        // Send request to WCF service
                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

                        Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving : "
                                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());


                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });

    }
```

My logcat is:

```
03-22 12:23:55.397: D/dalvikvm(115): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 424 objects / 21160 bytes in 233ms
03-22 12:24:01.748: D/WebInvoke(305): Saving : 415
03-22 12:26:43.081: D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8937348

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8307257/3366280